# Theme Ubercart product node and form in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, theming, forms, hooks, ubercart

I've been trying to do a "simple task" with Drupal 8. Using Ubercart 4.x, I want to totally change the product (add to cart) page.

For that I've created a twig file called **node--product.html.twig** and I've fully customized it. But the form is not there.

In order to have the form I've added this to my **.theme** file:

```
function theme_preprocess_node__product(&$variables) {
  // Creates a AddToCartForm for the given product (with node->id());
  $form_object = new \Drupal\uc_product\Form\AddToCartForm($variables['node']->id());
  $variables['product_form'] = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form_object, $variables['node']);
}
```

And now the form is accessible via the **product_form** variable in the **node--product.html.twig** file.

But that's where my issue start, I only find two ways of handling the form, either I do this:

```
{{ form }}
```

But then I have the form with the "normal" design, or I create it myself by doing something like this:

```
<form id="{{ product_form['#form_id'] }}" method="{{ product_form['#method'] }}" action="{{ product_form['#action'] }}">
  (...)
</form>
```

This way works since I can now customize the attributes, but I don't have access to their ID (I'm getting the values from the **node--product** node and not the form).

So my question is:
How can I handle this in order for me to fully customize the product node?

Comment: What happens if you `{{ kint(product_form) }}`?

Comment: Hi were you able to theme the checkout page by any change?